# Check if the "cell" of the "snake" is moving up/down or left/right so I can put the right icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I check if the "cell" of the "snake" is moving up/down or left/right so I can put the right icon? I have tried everything I know but its still not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snake Game</title>
        <style>
            html {
                background-color: #beb5b5;
            }
            canvas{
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 10%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

        <canvas id="snake" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
          
           <script>
const cvs = document.getElementById("snake");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


// Varje ruta i bilden är 32 px
const box = 30;


// Bilderna
const aplleImg = new Image();
aplleImg.src = "img/apple.png";
        
const snakeImg = new Image();
snakeImg.src = "img/snakeFront.png";
        
const snakeTailImg = new Image();
snakeTailImg.src = "img/snakeTailImg.png";


// Låtarna
let dead = new Audio();
let eat = new Audio();
let up = new Audio();
let right = new Audio();
let left = new Audio();
let down = new Audio();

dead.src = "audio/dead.mp3";
eat.src = "audio/eat.mp3";
up.src = "audio/up.mp3";
right.src = "audio/right.mp3";
left.src = "audio/left.mp3";
down.src = "audio/down.mp3";



// Deklarera snake som en array
let snake = [];

snake[0] = {    // Bestämmer "huvudets" koordinater
    x : 9 * box,
    y : 10 * box
};



// Deklarera apple som ett objekt
let apple = {
    x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1) * box,
    y : Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 3) * box
}


// Räknar hur många äpplen man har ätit
let score = 0;



//För att kunna kontrollera hur "snake" kommer att röra sig
let d;
document.addEventListener("keydown", direction);



// Här ritas allt i canvas

function draw(){
    
        let x, y; 
        for (var row = 0; row < 600/30; row++) { 
  
            for (var col = 0; col < 600/30; col++) { 

                x = row * 30; 
                y = col * 30; 
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 90);
                if ((row % 2 == 0) == (col % 2 == 0)) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#1cd037";
                } else {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#387441";                    

                }
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30); 
            } 
        } 
    
    
        for( let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) { // För att rita alla "celler"
            if(i == 0) {
               ctx.drawImage(snakeImg, snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
               } else {
                   ctx.drawImage(snakeTailImg, snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
               }
               
        }
          
        
    
    
    ctx.drawImage(aplleImg, apple.x, apple.y);
    
    // Allra första koordianten till första cellen/"huvudet"
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;
    
    // Var ?
    if( d == "LEFT") {
         snakeX -= box;
         snakeImg.src = "img/snakeLeft.png";
    }
    if( d == "UP") {
         snakeY -= box;
        snakeImg.src = "img/snakeUp.png";
    }
    if( d == "RIGHT") {
        snakeX += box;
        snakeImg.src = "img/snakeRight.png";
    }
    if( d == "DOWN") {
        snakeY += box;
        snakeImg.src = "img/snakeDown.png";
    }
    // När "snake" äter äpplet
    if(snakeX == apple.x && snakeY == apple.y){
        score++;
        eat.play();
        apple = {
            x : Math.floor(Math.random()*17+1) * box,
            y : Math.floor(Math.random()*15+3) * box
        }
        
        
    }else{
    
        snake.pop();
    }
    
    // Nytt "huvud"
    
    let newHead = {
        x : snakeX,
        y : snakeY
    }
    
    
    // Game Over
    
    if(snakeX < 0 || snakeX > 19 * box || snakeY < 3 * box || snakeY > 19 * box || collision(newHead, snake)){
        clearInterval(game);
        dead.play();
        localStorage.setItem("score", score);
        setTimeout(function() {location.href="slut.html";}, 600);
        
    }
    
    snake.unshift(newHead);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "45px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText(score, 2 * box, 1.6 * box);
    ctx.drawImage(aplleImg, 0.8 * box, 0.5 * box);
    
    ctx.font = "50px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText("Snake", 8 * box, 2 * box);
    
    ctx.font = "15px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText("Made by: Mohamad Shafeah", 14 * box, 2.8 * box);
}




// Beroende på knappen rör "snake" sig i olika håll
function direction (event) {
    let key = event.keyCode;
    if( key == 37 || key == 65 && d != "RIGHT"){   // Vänster och "A"
        left.play();
        d = "LEFT";
    }else if(key == 38 || key == 87 && d != "DOWN"){  // Uppe och "W"
        d = "UP";
        up.play();
    }else if(key == 39 || key == 68 && d != "LEFT"){  // Höger och "D"
        d = "RIGHT";
        right.play();
    }else if(key == 40 || key == 83 && d != "UP"){  //Nere och "S"
        d = "DOWN";
        down.play();
    }
}



// Kollar ifall det blir en kollision
function collision (head, array) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(head.x == array[i].x && head.y == array[i].y) {   // Ifall det blir så måste huvudet vara på samma koordinater som "cellen"    
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



// Anropa funktionen draw every 100 ms

let game = setInterval(draw, 100);
    </script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues that I found were:

1. In "function direction" you boolean logic is not correct. You have `key == 37 || key == 65 && d != "RIGHT"` for example. This says if key IS 37 OR key IS 65 AND d IS NOT RIGHT then do X. It should be `(key == 37 || key == 65) && d != "RIGHT"` for example. This will do a key is X or Key is Y AND check if d is not some value.
2. I suppect there could also be a scope issue with d. With out access to the assets to make this code runnable it's hard to tell. However, you should really have some sort of object to manage you variable. For example `const world = {}` then latter on add d to it like world.d = 'SomeValue'. That will fix the scope issue I belive is happening in `setInterval(draw, 100)`
3. I would also really change the name of you're lose html to something else in `setTimeout(function() {location.href="slut.html";}, 600)` Perhapse `lose.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snake Game</title>
        <style>
            html {
                background-color: #beb5b5;
            }
            canvas{
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 10%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

        <canvas id="snake" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
          
           <script>
const world = {}
const cvs = document.getElementById("snake");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


// Varje ruta i bilden är 32 px
const box = 30;


// Bilderna
const aplleImg = new Image();
aplleImg.src = "img/apple.png";
        
const snakeImg = new Image();
snakeImg.src = "img/snakeFront.png";
        
const snakeTailImg = new Image();
snakeTailImg.src = "img/snakeTailImg.png";


// Låtarna
let dead = new Audio();
let eat = new Audio();
let up = new Audio();
let right = new Audio();
let left = new Audio();
let down = new Audio();

dead.src = "audio/dead.mp3";
eat.src = "audio/eat.mp3";
up.src = "audio/up.mp3";
right.src = "audio/right.mp3";
left.src = "audio/left.mp3";
down.src = "audio/down.mp3";



// Deklarera snake som en array
let snake = [];

snake[0] = {    // Bestämmer "huvudets" koordinater
    x : 9 * box,
    y : 10 * box
};



// Deklarera apple som ett objekt
let apple = {
    x : Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1) * box,
    y : Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 + 3) * box
}


// Räknar hur många äpplen man har ätit
let score = 0;



//För att kunna kontrollera hur "snake" kommer att röra sig
world.d = null;
document.addEventListener("keydown", direction);



// Här ritas allt i canvas

function draw(){
    
        let x, y; 
        for (var row = 0; row < 600/30; row++) { 
  
            for (var col = 0; col < 600/30; col++) { 

                x = row * 30; 
                y = col * 30; 
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 90);
                if ((row % 2 == 0) == (col % 2 == 0)) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#1cd037";
                } else {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#387441";                    

                }
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30); 
            } 
        } 
    
    
        for( let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) { // För att rita alla "celler"
            if(i == 0) {
               ctx.drawImage(snakeImg, snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
               } else {
                   ctx.drawImage(snakeTailImg, snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
               }
               
        }
          
        
    
    
    ctx.drawImage(aplleImg, apple.x, apple.y);
    
    // Allra första koordianten till första cellen/"huvudet"
    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;
    
    // Var ?
    if( world.d == "LEFT") {
         snakeX -= box;
         console.log('snakeImg.src = "img/snakeLeft.png";')
         snakeImg.src = "img/snakeLeft.png";
    }
    if( world.d == "UP") {
         snakeY -= box;
  console.log('snakeImg.src = "img/snakeUp.png";')
        snakeImg.src = "img/snakeUp.png";
  
    }
    if( world.d == "RIGHT") {
        snakeX += box;
  console.log('snakeImg.src = "img/snakeRight.png";')
        snakeImg.src = "img/snakeRight.png";
    }
    if( world.d == "DOWN") {
        snakeY += box;
  console.log('snakeImg.src = "img/snakeDown.png";')
        snakeImg.src = "img/snakeDown.png";
    }
    // När "snake" äter äpplet
    if(snakeX == apple.x && snakeY == apple.y){
        score++;
        eat.play();
        apple = {
            x : Math.floor(Math.random()*17+1) * box,
            y : Math.floor(Math.random()*15+3) * box
        }
        
        
    }else{
    
        snake.pop();
    }
    
    // Nytt "huvud"
    
    let newHead = {
        x : snakeX,
        y : snakeY
    }
    
    
    // Game Over
    
    if(snakeX < 0 || snakeX > 19 * box || snakeY < 3 * box || snakeY > 19 * box || collision(newHead, snake)){
        clearInterval(game);
        dead.play();
        localStorage.setItem("score", score);
        setTimeout(function() {location.href="slut.html";}, 600);
        
    }
    
    snake.unshift(newHead);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "45px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText(score, 2 * box, 1.6 * box);
    ctx.drawImage(aplleImg, 0.8 * box, 0.5 * box);
    
    ctx.font = "50px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText("Snake", 8 * box, 2 * box);
    
    ctx.font = "15px Changa one";
    ctx.fillText("Made by: Mohamad Shafeah", 14 * box, 2.8 * box);
}




// Beroende på knappen rör "snake" sig i olika håll
function direction (event) {
    let key = event.keyCode;
    if( (key == 37 || key == 65) && world.d != "RIGHT"){   // Vänster och "A"
        left.play();
        world.d = "LEFT";
    }else if( (key == 38 || key == 87) && world.d != "DOWN"){  // Uppe och "W"
        world.d = "UP";
        up.play();
    }else if( (key == 39 || key == 68) && world.d != "LEFT"){  // Höger och "D"
        world.d = "RIGHT";
        right.play();
    }else if( (key == 40 || key == 83) && world.d != "UP"){  //Nere och "S"
        world.d = "DOWN";
        down.play();
    }
}



// Kollar ifall det blir en kollision
function collision (head, array) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(head.x == array[i].x && head.y == array[i].y) {   // Ifall det blir så måste huvudet vara på samma koordinater som "cellen"    
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



// Anropa funktionen draw every 100 ms

let game = setInterval(draw, 100);
    </script>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, But you didn't anwer my question :'(